# Finding other isosceles triangles with same circumference and area

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Question:**

A certain isosceles triangle has a base of $6$ cm and the other two sides are $5$ cm each. Are there any other isosceles triangles that has both the same circumference and same area?

**Attempted solution:**

The general approach I used was to calculate the area (A) and circumference (C) of the isosceles triangle in the question, develop a general expression for the two as a function of the base and the side, and then solve for these two quantities from a two-equation, two-variables set up.

$$C = 6 + 5+ +5 = 16~cm$$
$$A = \frac{bh}{2} = \frac{6 \sqrt{5^2 - 3^2}}{2} = \frac{6 \cdot 4}{2} = 12~cm$$

(The Pythagorean theorem gives the height)

I drew this picture where h is the height, y is the sides that are equal, x is half the base and thus 2x is the base.

[image]

Generally, we get:

$$C = 2x + 2y = 16 \Leftrightarrow x + y = 8$$

$$A = \frac{2xh}{2} = x \sqrt{y^2 - x^2} = 12$$

Solving the C equation for y and substituting in that for y in the A equation gives:

$$x \sqrt{(8-x)^2 - x^2} = 12$$
$$x \sqrt{64-16x+x^2 - x^2} = 12$$
$$x \sqrt{64-16x} = 12$$
$$\sqrt{64-16x} = \frac{12}{x}$$

Squaring both sides gives:

$$64-16x = \frac{144}{x^2}$$
$$64x^2-16x^3 = 144$$
$$16x^2(4-x) = 144$$
$$4-x = 144$$
$$x = 4- 144 = -140$$

However, a triangle cannot have a side that is $2x = 2 \cdot -140 = - 280 ~cm$, which suggests that this might have been a false solution introduced by squaring. So this would lead us to conclude that there are no other isosceles triangles with the stated properties, but there is one with

base = $1+\sqrt{13}$

other sides = $\frac{15-\sqrt{13}}{2}$

Somewhere, something must have gone terribly wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: $$16x^2(4-x) = 144$$
$$4-x = 144$$  
Are you sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have $4-x=144$ from $16x^2(4-x)=144$ which is correct.

You should know that one of the solutions of
$$64x^2-16x^3-144=0,$$
i.e.$$x^3-4x^2+9=0$$
is $\color{red}{x=3}$, so dividing this by $x-3$ gives you
$$(x-3)(x^2-x-3)=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in simplifying your cubic equation. You have $$16x^{3}-64x^{2}+144=0 \implies x^{3}-4x^{2}+9=0$$
Do you know how to check if this has any more roots than $3$ (which we already know about)?